# Table of Figures

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I added a table of figures.  I see it at the end of my document, however, higher up in the document I see the table of figures repeated.  This is what I see in this duplicate location:

The http://google.com/ Figure 1 Text1
Figure 2 Text2
Figure 3 Text3

The field codes look like:

The {HYPERLINK "http://google.com/"}{HYPERLINK\1"_Toc392975702"}...

When I delete this duplicate table of figure and then update again, it re-appears.

If I delete this whole section, then the same thing happens starting with another hyperlink.  It's like a regular hyperlink causes the table of figure hyperlinks to be brought in too.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your document somewhere where people can download it? FWIW this type of hyperlink field (the one with the _Toc) is typically generated by Word when it generates an index and is normally not visible unless you deliberately reveal the field codes in part of a TOC field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appeared to be some corruption in the document.  I copied sections to a new document and this went away.